# snowflake - Why does number of columns on a table impact the performance?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake database, I am trying to design a single dimension that will have personal attributes, employment attributes (job code, union code etc..) etc.. for a participant at a defined contributions plan level. The total number of columns would be around 170- 200 to begin with and would expand.
I thought the number of columns on a table doesn't impact performance and its the number of rows that impact performance in snowflake or in any database. However the below article says the number of columns will impact the performance and preferably around 100 columns is the optimal number.
https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008xD9ODSA0/does-the-number-of-columns-on-a-table-have-impact-on-performance
However the article doesn't say in detail why (it just states "more metadata is needed" ). How does that impact the performance?

Any advice would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: No select *. Only specific columns. The Dimension has about 200 million distinct particpant+plan rows, and 10 years worth history makes it almost 2 billion. The Fact has 2+ billion transactions. Legally, being a recordkeeping system, we have to preserve and expose these data to clients for analytics. When the PoC team created a copy of Dimension with reduced number of columns (but same 2 billions rows) The queries were returning within half or less of  the original time. So number of columns seem to have effect and hence I was curious. Will get exact details from PoC team and add it here

Answer (score 0):

you need to be clear about which aspect of "performance" is affected by the number of columns. Snowflake maintains metadata about the data held in columns so if you insert/update rows with a large number of columns then there's a large amount of metadata to manage which will have some performance impact.

If you're just querying a table then the number of columns the table has does not, in itself, affect performance. Obviously the more columns you select then the more data is being returned and this will affect performance; similarly, if you start putting filters on more columns in your query then this will affect performance.

However, regardless of the DBMS you are using, 200+ columns in a single table is starting to look excessive - from a management perspective if nothing else. It may be worth thinking about how to logically partition this table into multiple tables e.g. are there columns that will be very infrequently used; are there groups of columns that will normally be included in the same query; etc?

Comment: Thank you @NickW. I should have been clear that its the Query aspect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good articles on the Internet that explain Snowflake's micro-partition solution in great detail, so I will skip to the basics that help explain query performance is affected by the number of columns in a row.

It's not really about the number of columns, but rather the amount of storage that a row requires.  A lot of integer or date columns take up less space than super-long strings, for example.  Snowflake stores full records of data into a micro-partition of data, which are all roughly the same storage size.  So, the more data storage in a record, the less records are stored in a micro-partition.  The fewer records in a micro-partition means the more micro-partitions that need to be read from storage into the virtual warehouse that you are executing the query on.

So, if you are looking for 1 column of data for 1000 records, but the data is stored with 200 more fields, then Snowflake will need to read all of that into the warehouse just to get the 1 field you were looking for.  This read from storage is from blob storage, which is much slower, so reading micro-partitions is the part of the process that you'll want to minimize at all costs.

There are ways to tune for this, such as making smaller tables, using more integers (foreign keys) in your larger fact tables to reduce micro-partition counts, or leveraging materialized views for commonly queried combinations of fields to create a smaller subset of micro-partitions that Snowflake can automatically use.  These are just a few.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Mike. So it is about how the 500 MB limit of micropartition is reached it seems. If less column, more rows fits in, if more columns, less rows fit in. Correct?

Comment: I don't think that 500MB number is correct, but you have the concept correct.  If I recall correctly, micro-partitions are 16MB compressed typically, but I might be remembering the wrong number.